# (Java) Sum of While

Tags: java

So I wanted to sum all of the numbers i get from system.out.print` except 0 (the last one).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Kilometrikorvaus {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner lukija = new Scanner(System.in);
        int km= 0, luku= 0;
        while (km < 10) {
           System.out.print("Anna ajetut kilometrit (0 lopettaa): ");
           luku = lukija.nextInt();
           km++;
           if (luku == 0) {
              break;
           }     
        }

        while (luku != 0) {
           km = km + luku;
           System.out.println("Anna ajetut kilometrit (0 lopettaa): ");
           luku = lukija.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Yhteensä " + luku + " kilometriä"); 
    }
}
```

Here is what the Scanner should like:

```
Anna ajetut kilometrit (0 lopettaa): 12
Anna ajetut kilometrit (0 lopettaa): 13
Anna ajetut kilometrit (0 lopettaa): 10
Anna ajetut kilometrit (0 lopettaa): 5
Anna ajetut kilometrit (0 lopettaa):  0
**Yhteensä 40 kilometriä**
```

Mine :

```
Anna ajetut kilometrit (0 lopettaa): 12
Anna ajetut kilometrit (0 lopettaa): 13
Anna ajetut kilometrit (0 lopettaa): 10
Anna ajetut kilometrit (0 lopettaa): 5
Anna ajetut kilometrit (0 lopettaa):  0
**Yhteensä 0 kilometriä**
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a few minutes to read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on how to debug your code.

Comment: Print `km` instead of `luku`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch To the best of my understanding from a quick glance at the code, the first loop needs to be eliminated as well. Otherwise, the first loop completes with `luku` = 0, and the second loop never runs. The first loop's calculation is not correct anyway (`km++` instead of `km += luku`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have two separate loops, and don't properly handle the numbers that you receive. Your first loop receives the numbers, and compares them to zero, but does not sum them. Once you reach your second loop, `luku` is already zero so the second loop never runs and you obtain `0` as the output (since `luku`, which holds the last received value, is zero).

You can perform this with one loop:

```
 int km = 0, luku = 0;

  do {
    System.out.println("Anna ajetut kilometrit (0 lopettaa): ");
    luku = lukija.nextInt();
    km = km + luku;
  } while (luku != 0);
  System.out.println("Yhteensä " + km + " kilometriä");
```

The loop body prompts the user for an input (or zero to exit), adds it to `km` (the running total), and repeats as long as the input was not zero. At the end, the total value is printed (from the int variable `km`).

Answer (score 0):

You are changing value of luku, but never suming all together so I made new variable called max

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner lukija = new Scanner(System.in);
        int km= 0, luku= 0, max = 0 ; // added max
    while (km < 10) {
    System.out.print("Anna ajetut kilometrit (0 lopettaa): ");
      luku = lukija.nextInt();

max += luku; // change

 km++;
 if (luku == 0) {
     break;
 }

}
while (luku != 0) {
     km = km + luku;
max += km;
    System.out.println("Anna ajetut kilometrit (0 lopettaa): ");
    luku = lukija.nextInt();
}
System.out.println("Yhteensä " + max + " kilometriä"); 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the print statement in the last line you are printing luku variable which is 0 initialized in the first while loop.
For printing the sum print the km variable instead of luku.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typographical error (print km instead of luku).